# how do I sum the results of "for each in variable" function in Python?

Tags: python

so I have a function1 that converts card names that are string inputs into integers, ex. J, Q, K = 11, 12, 13, etc. and in my other function I called function1 using "for each":

```
def function2(x): # x has multiple letters like "JQK"
         for each in x:
         (function1(each))
```

now I want to sum the results from the function1, like J+Q+K, but idk how to do that.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow, may you please post the code for `function1` as well

Comment: Are you looking for `sum([function1(e) for e in x])`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything? If so, please edit your question and add what you've tried. You should think about what needs to be done in order to capture the output of each function call and increment a variable *outside* of that for loop with the result of each function call. Does that make sense?

Comment: What happened when you tried putting, for example, `python sum result of function` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+sum+result+of+function)?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you want to sum the values of `x`, thus

```
sum(function1(each) for each in x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new variable for the sum and in each iteration, add the result from function1 to the sum.

```py
def function2(x):
    s = 0
    for each in x:
        s += function1(each)
    return s
```

If you want to print the result, you can change `return s` to:  `print(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple:

```
num = 0
for x in whatever:
    num += x
```